# Vscrollbar doesn't disappear after titlebar click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, titlebar

There is a vscrollbar in my project which i want to make it disappear if the mouse
clicks anything outside it.
i already tried (Leave) and (Lost Focus) events and they were successful:

```
Private Sub VScrollBar1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Leave

    VScrollBar1.Visible = False

End Sub
Private Sub VScrollBar1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.LostFocus

    VScrollBar1.Visible = False

End Sub
```

the problem is when clicking the (Titlebar), nothing happens and scrollbar
is still visible, any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have the same *problem* with the Form itself, PictureBoxes, Panels, TableLayoutPanels, other Scrollbars etc. i.e., all controls that don't *steal* the focus.

Comment: I mean, maybe you can handle `WM_MOUSELEAVE` (or the MouseLeave event) instead. You could add the ScrollBar to a Panel (set it `TabStop = true`), slightly larger that the scrollbar and use the ScrollBar's MouseLeave event to hide it and the Panel MouseEnter event, with a small delay (100ms) to show it again, if/when the `ScrollBar.ClientRectangle` contains the `MousePosition` after the delay has elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titlebar has no click event but you can (create) one for it

your code works fine, you just need to add this code:

```
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Long = &HA1
Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If CLng(m.Msg) = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN Then
        Focus()
    End If
    MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
End Sub
```

this will get focus on your form, which will make your code work perfect...